# How to deploy a JAX-RS application?

Tags: java, deployment, servlets, jax-rs

The JAX-RS 1.1 specification says on page 6:

> If no Application subclass is present
>   the added servlet MUST be named:
>
> ```
> javax.ws.rs.core.Application
> ```

What is the added servlet? Could it be an arbitrary servlet?

> If an Application subclass is present
>   and there is already a servlet defined
>   that has a servlet initialization
>   parameter named:
>
> ```
> javax.ws.rs.Application
> ```

Again, what is "a servlet" here?

> If an Application subclass is present
>   that is not being handled by an
>   existing servlet then the servlet
>   added by the ContainerInitializer MUST
>   be named with the fully qualified name
>   of the Application subclass.

Does "the servlet added by the ContainerInitializer" mean that the servlets is added automatically? How would a configuration look like?

At the moment I use neither an Application class nor a web.xml and it works (with GlassFish 3.1). Does this deployment mechanism require a full class path scan, which could be slow with big libraries?

How to deploy on a Servlet container?

There is a confusing number of configuration options around in the web. See this [example with context params in the web.xml](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/putting-java-rest) (doesn't work for me!). What is the preferred way to deploy a JAX-RS application?

Comment: Surely this will depend on the implementation you are using? Resteasy, Jersey, ?

Comment: Shouldn't the deployment be independent from an implementation? I want to be able to deploy a JAX-RS application to an arbitrary Java EE 6 server without modification, like I would deploy a servlet application.

Comment: And what is the ContainerInitializer, anyway? The spec doesn't even mention it until page 6, and never again.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are a number of options for deploying into a Java EE 6 container (more specifically a Servlet 3.0 implementation):

The simplest is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then all the `@Path` and `@Provider` classes found in your web application will be available in the "default" JAX-RS application with a servlet URL pattern of `"/rest/*"`.

If you have one or more classes that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, you can specify like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.example.jaxrs.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.example.jaxrs.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You may want to do the above in case you wish to only return specific sets of `@Path`/`@Provider` classes on a URL (so you could have a second MyApplication2 with a different URL pattern above).

You can also skip the whole `web.xml` altogether and just annotate your `MyApplication` class wih `@ApplicationPath` which will serve as the URL pattern.  I would recommend keeping the `web.xml` in any case because you will probably have to add other information about the web application there anyway.

If you're wondering where the `servlet-class` comes from, it is automatically added in by the environment.  You can get an idea by looking at the Servlet 3.0 `ServletContext`.

Comment: I was getting messages in eclipse `Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet]: Could not find required class - com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet` Removing the servlet-class from web.xml as this answer fixed it!. Thanks

Comment: How can your web.xml be so minimal without a "resteasy.scan" property set to "true", so that it will automatically find the relevant resources? Wouldn't you still have to list out all your resources in web.xml?

Comment: @Amalgovinus Depending on the servlet container environment you use and the runtime, you don't have to have specific runtime properties set. This is the standard Java EE JAX-RS deployment configuration as specified in the Java EE spec.

Comment: If web.xml is essentially empty, would you then need to manually specify all the possible resources in your class that extends Application?

Comment: In case other are wondering about the answer's reference to ServletContext I think it hints towards addServlet(). Tomcat-Jersey Example: Tomcat scans the classpath jars and finds a (Jersey)ServletContainerInitializer registered in META-INf/services. The implementation is initialized and onStartup(...) is called. This method constructs Jerseys ServletContainer, and registers it with Tomcat by callling servletContext.addServlet(...). When its init() method is called it retrieves the Application impl. and (I assume) do the scan. It can now map URLs to the @Path annotated methods.

Comment: @Amalgovinus Depending on your container environment, you may or may not have to do that. Unfortunately I can't be more specific since various combinations of web containers with JAX-RS runtimes can support different setups. My answer is for the standard specification which should be interoperable across Java EE spec-compliant implementations. Like the first example of the web.xml in the answer, some form of class scanning may be done for any annotated Path resources automatically. You only have to specify the servlet-mapping.

Comment: @Hervian Yup, sorry for being ambiguous there (though I admit I had to refresh my own memory for this since it's been a few years). Servlets can be added pretty much like how you described (or filters and listeners). It's a powerful feature which comes with all that great responsibility too. :)

Answer (score 6):

With WAS 8.5, I change the web.xml to add:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.tada.rest.RestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My RestApplication look like :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> sets = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        sets.add(RestService.class);
        return sets;
    }
}
```

My RestService looks like

```
@Path("/tada")
public class RestService {
    @GET
    public String getSomething() {
        return "tada";
    }
}
```

And I add in the pom.xml the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Ik had to backport some functionality and this approach worked

Answer (score 2):

With Servlet3.0, follow this. This works for me.

```xml
<servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>your.restsrv.config.RESTConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I am getting `Broken Link: com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet` I can not find `jar` that contains this class, where I can find this `jar`

Answer (score -4):

As I said in the comment above, it all depends on the framework you want to use.

http://syrupsucker.blogspot.com/2008/10/deploying-jersey-in-tomcat-60.html for Jersey
http://syrupsucker.blogspot.com/2008/10/deploying-resteasy-in-tomcat-60.html for RESTeasy

As far as I know, JAX-RS does not contain a specification for deployment.

Comment: That is NOT CORRECT. JAX-RS DOES specify how an JAX-RS application is to be published in a Servlet container in a portable way in the Chapter Applications/Publication/Servlet. Besides, it allows implementations to provide other facilities to deploy.