# IntelliJ : How to expose API with JAX WS RS and @ApplicationPath

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jax-rs, intellij-13

It's probably a duplicate of [How to deploy a JAX-RS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072295/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application) but the answer doesn't match the intelliJ fact.

So here the problem :

I have a root class that normally expose n webservices :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class API extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestResourceClasses();
    }

    /**
     * Get the Rest resource classes.
     * @return the rest resource classes
     */
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(com.xxx.services.AuthService.class);
        ...
        resources.add(com.xxx.services.SimpleService.class);
        resources.add(com.xxx.tools.ResponseCorsFilter.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

and a RESTService class like :

```
@Path("/math")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SimpleService {

    private static Integer stack;

    @GET
    @Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
    public String add(@PathParam("a") Integer a, @PathParam("b") Integer b) {
        return Integer.toString(a + b);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/mult/{a}/{b}")
    public String mult(@PathParam("a") Integer a, @PathParam("b") Integer b) {
        return Integer.toString(a * b);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/stack")
    public String put(final Integer toStack) {
        stack = toStack;
        return Integer.toString(stack);
    }

}
```

Normally, after adding a glassfish server like :
[image: Debug/Run Configuration]

and run the solution with intelliJ, I can access to my webservice like :

```
http://localhost:8080/mediaweb/api/math/add/2/3
```

but nothing ... glassfish throw a 404.

but intelliJ still show me all my webservices in the debugger :

[image: Java enterprise tab in intelliJ]

How can I debug this ?

Comment: I've also try to put redeploy and Update resources, but it doesn't work ...

Comment: Add a `index.html` to the web root, with a simple hello world message, and just access `http://localhost:8080/mediaweb` from the browser. See if you see the page

Comment: You're right, I can't access to index.html

Comment: I'd imagine once you get that index up and running, the rest service should work

Comment: Also, I have a [2014-11-06 12:45:14,161] Artifact mediaweb:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

Comment: You can try to [run glassfish manually](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with IntelliJ.

Comment: I think it's probably caused by the CDI, Anyone know how to set up glassfish command in intelliJ to execute CDI entry point ?

Comment: Did you ever find out the problem?

Comment: Nop, but I'm not on this project anymore.