# cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Application in resteasy and EJB 3.0

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

I am getting exception com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.FrequentExceedingBean cannot be cast to cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Application

I am using EJB 3.0 and jboss 5.1 & resteasy

Please suggested to me, where is my mistake.

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.MyRestApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest/</param-value>
    </context-param>

 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.MyRestApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Edited:

```
package com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyRestApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> resourceObjects = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> resourceClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public  MyRestApplication() {
        resourceClasses.add(FrequentExceedingBean.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return resourceClasses;
    }
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return resourceObjects;
    }
}
```

i have added this code.. Still not working

Comment: does `com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.FrequentExceedingBean`extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`?

Comment: nope sir @P.J.Meisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class `com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.FrequentExceedingBean` should be the Aplication class as it is configured, it must extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` because the servlet container will instantiate an object of this class and then cast ist to `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` to be able to call it's `getClasses()` and `getSingletons()` method.

**Update**

Alas JBoss 5.1 has not yet Servlet 3.0., so you cannot confugre it without the web.xml.

Please check the accepted answer [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072295/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application) for the needed entries in the web.xml file. The configuration is different from yours in respect to where the classnames are. I myself haven't used web.xml configuration for quite a time anymore, so I am not so firm there.

Comment: Thanks. well explained

Comment: Based on your suggestion i made create class (MyRestApplication ).But i still getting com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.MyRestApplication cannot be cast to cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.Application .Please help me sir

Comment: And does this new class `MyRestApplication` extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`?

Answer (score 0):

your web.xml seems a little bit messy.

The question is: why should you provide your own implementation fo Application class?

If you have

`resteasy.scan = true`

you don't need anything else (exept for proper annotations on your Resource and Providers classes to publish your resources).

if you have

`resteasy.resources`

valued with a list of resources

you can omit the `resteasy.scan` parameter and explicitly provide a list of resources to be published (in this case you put `com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.MyRestApplication` and it's wrong, probably you should have put `com.sai.peps.ejb.frequentexceeding.FrequentExceedingBean`)

You may override Application class to move configuration out of web.xml and still have a strict control on the list of resources to be published with custom logic. Are you sure this is your need? If this is the case you should skip above configurations.

In any case choose one of the three methods