# How to fix 'cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet' error while trying to package REST App with Servlet

Tags: java, jax-rs, web.xml

I am trying to setup Angular 7 with a maven based back-end java project into a single war file. At the moment I am trying to configure the `web.xml` file where I am currently having this problem. I am not sure at all if my approach is valid or 'good' therefore I will first describe what I am trying to do (if you think better on this aspect please do correct me). 

So I have a couple of `JAX-RS` classes which I'd like to serve as a `REST API`. For this purpose I have created corresponding `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` classes to provide these REST components. Then I am including the `Application` classes in the `web.xml` file. Below are the files:

web.xml

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rmz/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Another variation of `web.xml` that I tried

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rmz/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Application class

```
public class StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> sets = new HashSet<>();
    sets.add(StammSolvaraJahrRest.class);
    return sets;
  }

}
```

The error that I get is: `java.lang.ClassCastException: backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet` and if I remove the `<servlet-class>` then I'll get `No servlet class has been specified for servlet`. I am following https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/configure.htm#RESTF183  and [How to deploy a JAX-RS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072295/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application) among others but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to define your JAX-RS servlet.

1) With Application Subclass like the one you have, you can skip the web.xml config and just add the application annotation

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication extends Application
```

2) With web.xml config

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>JAX-RS Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>package.hierarchy.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>package.hierarchy.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JaxRSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you skip the servlet mapping from the last one, it will use your your `@ApplicationPath` specified value, or `"/resources"` if the previous one is missing.

Comment: I wana go for the `web.xml` config but what I don't understand is why `servlet-name` at `servlet-mapping` and `servlet` have different values? Indeed, if I try your example, I'll get a `Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [JaxRSServlet]` error. If the naming is consistent then I'll get a `500 No servlet class has been specified for servlet`, which is indicating that I need a `servlet-class`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just what it says.  This line in your web.xml requires a `javax.servlet.Servlet`:

```
<servlet-class>backend.backendservice.StammSolvaraJahrRestApplication</servlet-class>
```

Since an `Application` is not a `javax.servlet.Servlet`, you're getting the error at runtime when your XML file is processed.

If you can, I would suggest that you start with a Spring Boot starter application.  Spring Boot handles all of this for you.  It can even embed a Tomcat server inside a jar file so that you can run your server like a simple Java application.  Doing this would save you having to worry about what you're dealing with here.

Comment: I can't work with Spring unfortunately. So then how am I supposed to configure this? I was following among others ´https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072295/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application´ and ´https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/configure.htm#RESTF183´

Comment: Is it possible that you're using the wrong definition of `Application`?  Maybe there is a `Application` class that is a `Servlet`, but you're using something else? - I don't remember the details of building up a war-based application in this way.  Spring Boot let me throw away all of my code in this area.

Comment: Nope its whats supposed to be: `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`

Comment: I just googled javax.ws.rs.core.Application.  That's just an Object, right?  So it isn't a Servlet, and so you can't use it like one.

Comment: I just looked at your second link.  I did so very quickly, but if you look, I don't think you are doing the same thing as what is shown there.  I don't see a case where the `<servlet-class>` tag is set to an instance of `Application`.  The `<servlet-name>` tag is, but not `<servlet-class>`.

Comment: It looks like the `<servlet-class>` tag has to refer to a `ServletContainer` class specific to whatever Servlet container.  See the docs for the `<servlet-class>` tag in that documentation.

Comment: Looks like @EmanuelRamirez.  Might have an answer for you.  I only gave you a diagnosis of the problem :)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for taking the time to look into this :)